# Executar JavaScript dentro de parâmetro da tag meta

Tags: javascript, html-meta-tag

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso que eu disse no titulo? Eu tentei desse jeito mas me parece que ele não executa a função:

```
<script>
function imgPrincProdu(){
    return $('.flickity-slider > img').attr('src');
}
</script>
<meta property="og:image" content="javascript:imgPrincProdu()" />
```

Comment: Por quê não atribui um `id` para a *tag* e faz no JS algo como `setAttribute("content", "novo valor")`?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo, Anderson, se não for incomodo?

Comment: Seria <meta id="meuid"> e no JS eu pegar o #meuid e adicionar o valor?

Comment: Ja consegui contato com a plataforma e fazer direto no PHP, ai ficou mais dinâmico e funcional. Obrigado, Anderson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentei, basta você atribuitr um `id` para sua *tag* e utilizar o método `setAttribute` para definir o novo valor. Veja o exemplo abaixo, onde atribuo "novo valor" ao atributo `content` da *tag*:

```js
const ogImage = document.getElementById("og-image");

ogImage.setAttribute("content", "Novo valor");
```

```html
<meta id="og-image" property="og:image" content="" />
```

Para comprovar que o valor foi alterado basta inspecionar a página e buscar a *tag* dentro da *body* do *snippet*. Se deu tudo certo, verá `content="Novo valor"`.